# How to reinstall GRUB on an LVM system?

Tags: boot, grub2, lvm

I have an old system installed Ubuntu 18.04 (desktop). It was partitioned `/boot/efi` on `/dev/sda1`, `/boot` on `/dev/sda2`, and `/` on `/dev/sda3` (with LVM). The `/boot` partition was too small to install new packages. Therefore, I umounted the `/boot` and the `/boot/efi` partitions, and commented mounting `/boot` in `/etc/fstab`. Later, I reinstalled Ubuntu 20.04 on `/boot`, which is on the LVM volume.

The installation was successful. However, when I reboot the system, it boots the old `/boot` partition with the old kernel.

Summary:

1. `/dev/sda1` is the old `/boot/efi` partition and `/dev/sda2` is the old `/boot` partition.
2. New kernels are installed on `/boot` on an LVM volume.
3. The bootloader always boots the old `/boot` partition first.

How to boot with the new kernel? Should I type the commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

I worry that the grub might be installed with the old kernel or break my GRUB menu.
Besides, I should remove the old `/boot/efi` in `/etc/fstab`.

Thanks a lot!

Appendix:

`lsblk`

```
sda                       8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1                    8:1    0   512M  0 part
├─sda2                    8:2    0   488M  0 part
└─sda3                    8:3    0   1.8T  0 part
  ├─gs--vg-root         253:0    0     9T  0 lvm  /
  └─gs--vg-swap_1       253:1    0 127.9G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
```

`/etc/fstab`

```
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
/dev/mapper/gs--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during installation
#UUID=d053f15f-12bc-4ae4-96e5-8d28aeb997ed /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
#UUID=7D6D-081F  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/gs--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
UUID=7D6D-081F  /boot/efi       vfat    defaults      0       1
```